# update auto Create_at & Update_at columns at laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

here some simple code I have. Actually I was trying to insert some Tag to my database and no problem to that.but once insert my tag `created_at` & `updated_at` columns not update and just NULL
how can i update auto this fields?
I don't have any model
just migration
here my tag migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('tag');
        $table->timestamps(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eloquent to auto update `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

```
Model::create($data);
Model::update($data);
```

When you're using raw queries or query builder, you'll need to update these fields manually.

```
DB::table('table_name')
  ->insert(['tag' => 'some_tag', 'created_at' => Carbon::now()]);
```

Comment: tnx but i forgot to say i use query Builder and don't know Eloquent

Comment: @siros you can learn Eloquent or update these fields manually. )